# Looping through ConcurrentDictionary while modifying values

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, concurrentdictionary

I have a static `ConcurrentDictionary` in a `static` class. In the static constructor of the class, I call a private method via `Task.Run` to indefinitely loop through the dictionary and remove items that have expired, i.e. a significant amount of time has passed since they were added and as such need to be removed (this is determined by by inspecting a property on each `CustomItem` value of each item in the dictionary):

```
public static class ItemsHolder
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, CustomItem> Items = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, CustomItem>();

   // ...

    static ItemsHolder
    {
        Task.Run(() => DeleteExpired());
    }

    private static async Task DeleteExpired()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // check if dictionary is empty and if yes, 
            // await Task.Delay a bit, etc - omitted for brevity

            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                var guid = item.Key;
                var customItem = item.Value;

                if (customItem.ConditionToRemoveItemFromDictionaryHere)
                {

                    var removeItem = Items.TryRemove(guid, out _);

                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other parts of the code (outside of this class), items are being added to this dictionary and removed based on other conditions. Effectively `DeleteExpired()` is there to clean out items that could not be removed from the dictionary (in other parts of the code, for XYZ reasons)

I see that `DeleteExpired()` keeps popping up in my metrics in tools such as dotTrace in R# as occupying CPU time. I know that iterating through the concurrent dictionary while other threads might be adding/removing is lock-free and should be safe to do, but I'm not sure whether this is the most effective way of doing so. Is there a more effective/efficient way of doing so?

Comment: You can use a SortedDictionary to order items by expiry date and pull from the head of that list. It's not concurrent but you can use N such lists and use lock sharding which should help a lot.

Comment: hi @usr, can you explain why use `N` such lists and what you mean by lock sharding? Is that manually locking the collection while performing operations on it?

Comment: @globetrotter - You can't remove items from a collection that you're iterating over. It doesn't matter if they are a `Concurrent*` or standard collection. This is true with a single-thread. It is worse with multiple threads.

Comment: If there is just one list all threads contend on that lock. Maybe you are using a ConcurrentDictionary because there is a lot of action from many threads. But actually you could maybe make this far more efficient by using a simple Dictionary and lock it. If the write frequency is not too high this would make iteration a lot faster. Depends on your write frequency. But lock sharding is a solution to write contention. Btw, you could use lock sharding and N Dictionary instances as well. That way delete iteration would be fast as well as writes.

Comment: `// check if dictionary is empty and if yes, await Task.Delay a bit, etc - omitted for brevity`. Are you implying you wait *only* if the dictionary is empty? If so, then you have your performance hog.

Comment: @Enigmativity pretty sure removal while enumerating on the concurrent collections [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2729316/1199044).

Comment: @A.Chiesa yes, I only asynchronously wait if the dictionary is empty so i don't attempt to enumerate with `foreach` if not. How would you suggest doing it? Sleeping after each removal iteration? What benefit would that give?

Comment: @globetrotter - Sorry, my mistake. I just built a test and you're right. Well that's going to save me some tears in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You're not waiting between each iteration, if the dictionary is not empty.

The `while (true)` makes a thread spin furiously and without rest (quite literally). You *must* absolutely wait between each check.

Without delay or sleep, one thread is going to continuously consume a whole core of your CPU (or at least it's going to try to do it), and this is the reason for the anomaly in performance.

I would write it as:

```
while(true) {
  Items.Where(pair => pair.Value.ConditionToRemoveItemFromDictionaryHere)
    .Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(guid => Items.TryRemove(guid, out _));

  // thread.sleep, task delay or whatever suits your needs
}
```

Comment: There's a code comment there where he said he left out waiting. And this is material to the question, because he's having a perf issue despite properly waiting.

Comment: @usr there is a comment from the OP where i states "yes, I only asynchronously wait if the dictionary is empty so i don't attempt to enumerate with foreach if not". My native language is not english, but I think this means that he doesn't wait if the collection is not empty.

Comment: Oh, I see. Too bad that the true code was omitted. It would have been clearer that this is, likely, the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I would have suggested to use a background task scheduler such as **Quartz**, as schedulers are especially made for that use case.

Create the Task for cleaning the dictionary:

```
public class CleanExpiredJob : IJob
{
    // Your ConcurrentDictionary value will be injected by the scheduler
    public ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> Items {private get; set;}
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                var guid = item.Key;
                var customItem = item.Value;

                if (customItem.ConditionToRemoveItemFromDictionaryHere)
                {

                    var removeItem = Items.TryRemove(guid, out _);

                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, add the scheduler to your Application start:

```
    // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
    NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
    };
    var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
    var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

    await scheduler.Start();
    var job = JobBuilder.Create<CleanExpiredJob>().Build();

    // Add your dictionary here
    // Notice: Keep the same name as the property in the job for injection
    job.JobDataMap["Items"] = Items;

    // Set the job to run every 10 seconds
    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```